# problem : using the same css but another image have been pushed upwards

Tags: html, css

I am newbie with html css and here is my problem.

I code a very simple html css program as you can see in this link

```
https ://codepen.io/anhbui2904/pen/KKXQKGg
```

And, my problem is, as you can see in the result, the left square has been pushed upward.

My problem is, I coded it as the same with another square, as you can see in the code.

Maybe it is because of the course-item css ?

Could you please help me to solve this problem to make it to be the same height ? Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You're nesting `class="col"` containers. Each of which brings some more `margin-top` along with it. The left block is in only in 1 `col`, but the others are wrapped within 2 layers of it.

If your goal is to have 4 similar/aligned blocks then the structure of your HTML is a bit odd. Why not just have 4 blocks in the same parent ?

Answer (score 1):

It's because the structure is different, for class category ,it's nested inside row and column

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col l-3 m-0 c-0">
  <div class="category">
```

but for class course-item, it's nested inside 2 sets of row and column.

```
<div class="col l-9 m-12 c-12">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col l-4 m-6 c-12">
   <div class="course-item">
```

You can use css for category class to align e.g `margin-top`

Comment: @akirirk your answer is so great, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Why you are nesting the first col seperately. Nest all the col inside single parent.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).